# elm reactor http://localhost:8000/ is empty

Tags: elm

I am just starting with Elm locally.

I did

```
elm init
```

```
Hello! Elm projects always start with an elm.json file. I can create them!
...
Check out <https://elm-lang.org/0.19.1/init> for all the answers!
...
```

Then copy into src/Main.elm from Ellie app https://ellie-app.com/new

(I also tried empty and https://github.com/elm/elm-lang.org projects)

```
elm reactor
```

And when I run the `elm reactor`, I see nothing at http://localhost:8000/ :
browser just waits response forever, no errors in terminal, no errors or activity in browser console, just waiting.

[image]

[image]

P.S. using macBook with M1 chip, running macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261).
Elm 0.19.1
Trying Firefox and Chrome, no errors in Terminal or in Browser console.

P.P.S. To recreate

```
elm init
elm make
elm reactor
```

Comment: I've tried it and it works for me. Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: That is exactly the strange thing: no errors in console, no activity in Network, the port http://localhost:8000 is accepting connection, so the browser is waiting, but nothing comes out, even any error in terminal where `elm reactor` is launched, nor in browser. I think something may be missing in my setup or system. But from elm reactor, there should be some timeouts configured or logs what exactly it is doing now...

Comment: Does the server return some page? Can you add that response to your question? It might be that somehow the linking between html and js generated from Elm is not working properly. Also, check that your elm.json file is generated correctly, especially the `source-directories` property is relevant here.

Comment: Server returns nothing, no response, but the port is open and connection is created, that is why browser is waiting and not just saying that unavailable. Project created with `elm init`

Comment: I meant that maybe `elm init` with its default made some incorrect assumptions. `elm make` is not required when using `elm reactor`, but does it compile your files correctly? Compiled files should appear in `build` directory.

Comment: I trying on empty and https://github.com/elm/elm-lang.org project as well. The problem definitely is not related to project content.

Comment: Could it be a browser issue or browser extension? You could try a different browser.

Comment: You could also try curl: `curl http://localhost:8000` should dump out some HTML in your terminal.

Comment: Just tried with `curl http://localhost:8000` and Edge browser. The same nothingness. I should better just forget about this `elm reactor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution should have been: "restart your computer".

It was silly of me, as I had exactly .js script running,
that gave descibed behavior: accepting connections,
but returning nothing, and never ending connection.

```js
const http = require("http");

const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;

const requestListener = function (req, res) {};

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

Once I stopped that service (when restarting IDE), I got reactor accessible

[image]

Comment: Be sure to mark your own answer as accepted, to help other people know there's a solution!